# iTunes RSS Feed in JSON - Read in JAVA Webapps

Tags: java, json, itunes

I am building a web application in which I want to display iTunes top 10 Songs and iTunes top 10 albums.

I have used https://rss.itunes.apple.com/  link to generate it and changed from XML to json.

http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=10/json

I am getting JSON from the above link. And can view in JSON Viewer

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=10/json

However, I am confuse on how to read the JSON Object so that I can get the required fields. (entry > title)

I am able to get to the entry and loop through the array to get all the title. However I am not sure about how to get label.

```
URL url = new URL("http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=10/json");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject itunesJsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

        JSONObject feedJsonOject = itunesJsonObject.getJSONObject("feed");        
        JSONArray arrayJsonObject = feedJsonOject.getJSONArray("entry");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayJsonObject.length() ; i++){                        

            list.add(arrayJsonObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));            
        }

        for(String e: list){
            log.debug("JSON Object : " + e.toString());
        }
```

In log.debug I am geeting following which includes label.

JSON Object : {"label":"Happy (from \"Despicable Me 2\") - Pharrell Williams"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Trumpets - Jason Derulo"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Rude - MAGIC!"}

JSON Object : {"label":"All of Me - John Legend"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Free (feat. Emeli SandÃ©) - Rudimental"}

JSON Object : {"label":"I See Fire - Ed Sheeran"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Timber (feat. Ke$ha) - Pitbull"}

JSON Object : {"label":"God Only Knows - MKTO"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Like a Drum - Guy Sebastian"}

JSON Object : {"label":"Hey Brother - Avicii"}

My question is on how to get just the title without curly brackets and word label. 
Also in JSON entry : im:collection has three objects (im:name, link and im:contentType). How to get them invididually.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` is an object with a field called `label`, so you'll have to unpack that as well. Something like this might work:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayJsonObject.length() ; i++){                        
    list.add(arrayJsonObject.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("title").getString("label");            
}
```

Partial raw JSON:

```
"title": {
    "label": "Happy (from \"Despicable Me 2\") - Pharrell Williams"
},
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked perfect. Thanks for the answer.